# DB Microsoft Excel Driver

Tags: java, excel, jdbc

somebody knows where i could find the driver for Microsoft Excel Driver Data Base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will get the driver from [https://xlsql.dev.java.net](https://xlsql.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=1658&expandFolder=1658&folderID=0)
2. [Here is the sample application for the same](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/ReaddatafromExcel.htm)